# Обработка button

Tags: javascript

Только начал изучение `JS`, поэтому, вероятнее всего, допустил какую-то глупую ошибку. Замысел такой: пользователь вводит кличку, породу и вес собаки. Жмет на кнопку, вызывается функция, которая считывает инфу с полей, создает объект, передавая ему, считанные значения и вызывает метод объекта, который в свою очередь производит небольшую проверку по весу и выводит соответствующее сообщение. Но работает это иначе: в самом начале загрузки `HTML` выводится сообщение ": Тят!" и дальше кнопка не работает. Не могу понять почему, второй час вожусь.

```js
window.onload = init;

function init(){
 var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
 button.onclick = handleButtonClick();
}

function handleButtonClick(){
 var textInput = document.getElementById("dogName");
 var dogName = textInput.value;
 var textInput = document.getElementById("dogBreed");
 var dogBreed = textInput.value;
 var textInput = document.getElementById("dogWeight");
 var dogWeight = textInput.value;
 var dog1 = new Dog(dogName, dogBreed, dogWeight);
 dog1.bark();
}

function Dog(name, breed, weight){
 this.name = name;
 this.breed = breed;
 this.weight = weight;
 this.bark = function(){
  if (this.weight > 25){
   alert(this.name + ": Вуф!!!");
  } else {
   alert(this.name + ": Тяв!");
  }
 };
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="dogName" size="40" placeholder="Кличка собаки"><br>
  <input type="text" id="dogBreed" size="40" placeholder="Порода собаки"><br>
  <input type="text" id="dogWeight" size="40" placeholder="Вес собаки"><br>
  <input type="button" id="addButton" value="Голос!">
</form>
```

Comment: для того, чтоб участники форума могли понять что происхоит, загрузите код на jsfiddle. чтоб можно было сразу запустить. stackoverflow предоставляет такую возможность

Comment: у вас в самом начале js дока написано : window.onload = init; 
что вы хотите этим сделать?

Comment: @Vlad Teryoshin Ну в книге написано, что нужно так написать, чтобы функция с обработкой нажатия кнопки работала только после полной загрузки DOM.

Comment: дело в том, что она и вызывается сразу после загрузки страницы..

Comment: сделайте пожалуйста, так, как я говорил с jsfiddle. просто скопируйте туда код и удалите скриншоты отсюда, никто просто не будет руками переписывать код себе

Comment: @VladTeryoshin jsfiddle и аналоги не следует использовать на stackoverflow, здесь есть встроенные инструменты для создания запускаемых сниппетов (сейчас он в вопросе уже добавлен)

Comment: @andreymal вы не совсем разобрались в вопросе, вопрос был написан со скриншотами. я попросил подключить jsfiddle...он встроен

Comment: @VladTeryoshin jsfiddle — это сторонний веб-сайт, который никогда не был и скорее всего никогда не будет встроен в stackoverflow. Хотя бы потому, что в stackoverflow уже давно встроены сниппеты, зачем сюда ещё jsfiddle пихать?

Comment: @andreymal, слушай, ты искал повода прикопаться? сниппет похож на фиддл, я так написал, ты если хочешь поумничать, пойди поотвечай на вопросы, а не устраивай тут черт знает что

Comment: @VladTeryoshin сниппет и «фиддл» это разные вещи. Прекращайте вводить людей в заблуждение. jsfiddle запрещён на stackoverflow: сайт выдаёт ошибку, если в вопросе добавить ссылку на jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А если написать так:

```
button.onclick = handleButtonClick;
```

Comment: Спасибо! говорю же, вероятнее всего глупейшая ошибка)))

Comment: @Kafka угу. можно нажимать галку рядом с ответом. он наверняка верный. и всегда...всегда, когда есть проблемы с кодом - вставляйте его в вопрос текстом, а не скриншотами. особенно для js,html,css на ruSO есть встроенный сниппет который исполняет код

Comment: бубликат же, мог бы и поискать :)

Comment: @Grundy офигенное название "Как куда-нибудь передать функцию". Хотя если б мне было 12 - наверное я действительно по такому названию искал бы дубль